# angular dynamic routerLink sometimes with queryParam

Tags: angular

#### I am using the router link like this

```
[routerLink]="[item.link]"
```

#### That works

if `item.link` is a string without queryparams. ie: `/search`

#### It doesnt work

if I have query parameters. ie: `/search?q=dog`

## Question

Is there one way to write routerLink so it will work with `/search` and `/search?q=dog`? if not is there a function that will do it?

## My Attempt (looking for better. Maybe all html?)

```
routTo(link) {
    if (link.includes('?')) {
      let tmp = link.split('?');
      this.router.navigate([`/${tmp[0]}`], { queryParams: { [tmp[1].split('=')[0]]: tmp[1].split('=')[1] } });
    } else {
      this.router.navigate([link]);
    }
    setTimeout(() => this.closeDrawer(), 350);
  }
```

Comment: I think you need to adjust your routes in your routing module to accept query strings for the path `/search`, and you will handle the different query strings in your search component.

Answer (score 0):

To pass query params in the template, you can do this:

```html
<a [routerLink]="['../']" [queryParams]="{q: 'dog'}">Somewhere</a>
```

Comment: I know that much.. But because this is dynamic. I am looking for a way to handle with or without queryparams